# Use "and" many times in loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I tried to use `and` in a `while` loop but it seems to not work well.  For example:

```
while (A1==0) and (A2==0) and (A3==0) and (A4==0):
```

With this one, it seems to end the loop for the first and second `and`, and not always all the conditions satisfied. Is this the wrong way to use `and` with a `while` loop?

Below is the code:

```
import random
B1=0
B2=0
B3=0
B4=0
A = random.randrange(1,5)
while all([B1==0, B2==0, B3==0, B4==0]):
    if A != B1:
        B1 = A
        print(B1)
    A = random.randrange(1,5)
    if (A!= B2) and (A!= B1):
        B2 = A
        print(B2)
    A = random.randrange(1,5)
    if (A!= B3) and (A!= B2) and (A!= B1):
        B3=A
        print(B3)
    A = random.randrange(1,5)
    if (A!= B4) and (A!= B3) and (A!= B2) and (A!= B1):
        B4=A
        print(B4)
```

I want to print 1,2,3,4 in random order but it usually prints 2 or 3 of them.

Comment: Show us the rest of your code.

Comment: In `and` if the first condition `A1 == 0` is false then none other conditions are evaluated. what is your expected behaviour ?

Comment: Somewhere either A1,A2,A3 or A4 is becoming non-zero (or you have a break statement)... look for that

Comment: You can use the `all()` builtin to clean this up a bit `while all([A1==0, A2==0, A3==0, A4==0])`

Comment: If you want that loop to continue while any of those statements are `True` you should be using `or` or the `any()` built in like so: `while any([A1==0, A2==0, A3==0, A4==0])`

Comment: I get the feeling @IanAuld is the only one understanding the real issue

Comment: Remember not to forget [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) when negating conditionals. "while not a and not b" is not the opposite of "until a and b".

Comment: Thank you guys. The code is included. It doesnt work with "all"

Comment: There were no guarantees of it working with `all`; just that it'd look a bit cleaner if you did it that way.

Comment: @Kevin: Thank you. You just clarify that for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In spite of the fact that something is short-circuiting (`and` stops evaluation at the first falsy result), there's a more concise way to write this using `all`:

```
while all([A1 == 0, A2 == 0, A3 == 0, A4 == 0]):
    # Work here
```

While all of the values being generated inside of the list are being evaluated (and hence are not short-circuiting), `all` will return `False` on the first falsy occurrence.

---

Since you've added the code you're using, your expressions will *never be true* on the second iteration.  `random.randrange(1, 5)` will [only generate values between 1 and 5 exclusive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange).  Reduce the start value to 0 so that you have a *chance* of it generating a 0.

---

Since you've clarified what you want to do, then all you need to do is just generate four random values, and check if they match up against a set containing the values you want.

```
result = []
expected = {1, 2, 3, 4}
while set(result) != expected:
    # Surely there's a better method to generate this...
    result = [random.randint(1, 4), random.randint(1, 4),
              random.randint(1, 4), random.randint(1, 4)]
print result
```

Comment: It's not the same, all expressions will be evaluated which goes against the very nature of "short-circuiting".

Comment: @JeffMercado:  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: You are building a list of the values of the expression. The _values_, they're all being evaluated.

Comment: Thank you Makoto. I tried with "all" but it doesn't work as well. I included the code above.

Comment: @Makoto: I want to generate 1,2,3,4 and arrange them in random order.

Comment: @Makoto: Edited. Can you suggest a solution for this problem mate?